# Placement Position of Content on a Page

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard 1.4 and playing around with the Projection Widget.

One thing I am wondering about is how to control the positioning of the content on the Page.

I understand the widgets are placed in the designated zone, but what if I want to put the contents of the projection modules somewhere within the page content?

For Example :

```
Title

Some Page content here

Projection Module content

Some more Page content here
```

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically use placement.info to change the order of parts on the rendered page.

Comment: But wouldn't that still be either before Page Content or after Page Content? Or can that be between the Page content?

Comment: Oh you mean you are using a projection widget? In that case, use a projection page instead.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the tip. I didn't know about the Projection page until now! One last thing - I still can't figure out a way to place list content within page content. How can one achieve that using Placement.info?

Comment: Like with any shape. You might want to use shape tracing to find out.

Comment: Once I had created an alternate, the shape tracing stopped giving me any information about the shapes placement. I ended up querying the part from the view.

Comment: Giving you the answer, as I believe this does not happen in the normal scenario...